# How do I include Visual C++ 2010 redistribuable in my setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

When my application runs, it requires that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) is installed. How do I include it in my app setup?

I use the setup wizard of Visual Studio 2010 to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would include the VC++ 2010 merge module into the setup project.  Information on redistribution via merge module can be found in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290.aspx).  General resitribution is available from the [parent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[Prerequisites Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx)

> This dialog box specifies which prerequisite components are installed,
>   how they are installed, and which order the packages are installed.
>
> To access this dialog box, select a project node in Solution Explorer,
>   and then, on the Project menu, click Properties. When the Project
>   Designer appears, click the Publish tab. On the Publish page, click
>   Prerequisites. For Setup projects, on the Project menu, click
>   Properties. When the Property Pages dialog box appears, click
>   Prerequisites.

it's all explained here, follow the suggested steps then add VC++ 2010 runtime as prerequisite. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following articles. They explain how to include requisite resources in a setup project.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bxs9z6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx) project, I would recommend using [Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> **Redistributing By Using Merge Modules**
>
> Visual Studio installs several merge modules for each Visual C++
>   component that may be redistributed with your application. They may be
>   found in the Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules folder. Each of
>   these merge modules may be used to deploy Visual C++ DLLs to the
>   target system.

Adding merge modules to your project is fairly [straight forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x727h8b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> **To add a merge module to a deployment project**
>
> 1. Select the deployment project in Solution Explorer.
> 2. On the Project menu, point to Add, and then click Merge Module.
> 3. In the resulting Add Modules dialog box, browse to the location of the
>      merge module that you want to add.

Comment: Forgive the silly question, but how can I find out which merge modules I need to add? The dependencies are not correctly identified in VS2013 Installer Projects. Cheers!

Comment: @Colin. I'm not sure if there's an exact way of doing this but would recommend to first know what dll dependencies your application/library has. Once you've identified those you can see (by searching) if there is a merge module for that dependency. Generally the merge modules exist for redistributable packages like the VC++ runtime, etc.